# Issue with parsing (via JavaScript) an automatically created (via Python) JSON file

Tags: javascript, python, json

A few days ago I got an order from a local company to make them a mobile app. The design and UI is almost ready but there are some issues regarding its logic. One of these issues is following: they want their services listed on a lower part of the body of the app.

I started thinking about this yesterday and came up with this idea: I'm scraping their website, collecting the needed data and making an array of json objects, which I write to a .json file with python. Then using javascript I'm parsing this .json file and extracting the necessary parts from it to show in a div... Python creates the json file successfully but when JavaScript tries to parse it, it is unsuccessful. I checked with console logging and it says `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`, which is the beginning of my JSON file.

I am presenting you my Python, JS, JSON files and the relevant parts of my HTML file.

**Python**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def make_json_file():
    titles = []
    captions = []
    sources = []

    serv_url = 'http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/145/150'
    full_page = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(serv_url).read(), "html.parser")

    links = full_page.findAll('a', {'class': 'readmore'})
    for i in range(0, len(links), 2):
        source = links[i]['href']
        sources.append(source)

        title = links[i].findAll('div')[1].string
        titles.append(title)

        caption = 'http://www.theclub.az/' + links[i].findAll('a')[0].img['src']
        captions.append(caption)

    products = [{"title": t, "caption": c, "source": s} for t, c, s in zip(titles, captions, sources)]
    content = json.dumps(products, ensure_ascii=False)

    with open('products.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('products = ')
        json.dump(content, outfile)
        outfile.write(';')


make_json_file()
```

**It creates this JSON file (products.json)**

```
products = "[{\"title\": \"\u0130DMAN ZALI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/8223682236sport.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/194\"}, {\"title\": \"\u00dcZG\u00dc\u00c7\u00dcL\u00dcK HOVUZU\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/8394983949hovuz.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/195\"}, {\"title\": \"KARD\u0130O AL\u018fTL\u018fR ZALI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/6862168621card.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/196\"}, {\"title\": \"A\u011eIRL\u0130Q AL\u018fTL\u018fR\u0130 ZALI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/2713327133sport.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/208\"}, {\"title\": \"F\u018fRD\u0130 M\u018f\u015e\u011e\u018fL\u018f\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/58989589891.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/197\"}, {\"title\": \"S\u00dcN\u0130 QAYA\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/4781247812qaya.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/198\"}, {\"title\": \"SPORT CAFE\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/60776607764.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/201\"}, {\"title\": \"THE CLUB SPA\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/17042spa.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/216\"}, {\"title\": \"FITNES STUDIYA 1\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/34042340421.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/209\"}, {\"title\": \"FITNES STUDIYA 2\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/48637486371.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/210\"}, {\"title\": \"TEN\u0130S KORTU\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/24234242341.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/203\"}, {\"title\": \"SKVO\u015e KORTLAR\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/64949649492.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/204\"}, {\"title\": \"COFFEE SHOP\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/55114551141.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/202\"}, {\"title\": \"U\u015eAQ OTA\u011eI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/55813558131.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/206\"}, {\"title\": \"GOLF SIMULYATOR\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/3846210.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/199\"}, {\"title\": \"BILYARD OTA\u011eI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/67419674191.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/205\"}, {\"title\": \"SPORT SHOP\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/95621956211.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/207\"}, {\"title\": \"SAUNA/BUXAR OTA\u011eI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/2131719.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/211\"}, {\"title\": \"SOLARIUM\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/9097520.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/212\"}, {\"title\": \"G\u00d6Z\u018fLL\u0130K SALONU\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/4677721.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/213\"}, {\"title\": \"B\u018fRB\u018fR SALONU\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/3459922.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/214\"}, {\"title\": \"DZ\u00dcDO D\u018fRSL\u018fR\u0130\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/21924judo.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/242\"}]";
```

**HTML and JavaScript**

```js
//s.js
window.onload = function() {
  var prods = document.getElementById("prods");
  var products = JSON.parse(products)
  prods.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
    var prod = products[i];
    prods.innerHTML += '<div class="prd_div"><a class="prd_par" href="' + prod.source + '"><img src="' + prod.caption + '" class="prd" /><p>' + prod.title + '</p></a></div>';
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="products.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="prods"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="s.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Where am I doing the mistake? Please, help!

Comment: Your `json` file is **not** a valid json file. You should not add anything to the file, just use `json.dump` without anything else

Comment: @Dekel I tried it but then how can my javascript file communicate with it? I mean, how can it recognize which variable I'm talking about?

Comment: read about ajax

Comment: JSON value is valid, however that is not a json file

Comment: JSON file shall not have `products =` part.. instead use something like `{ 'products':[ ... ] }`

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I though was the json value not the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the you should make an [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to get JSON. So in your html you should remove this line

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="products.json"></script>
```

And in your JS file you should make your ajax like this:

```
function loadAjax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     console.log(this.responseText) // here you will got the whole json
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "products.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Im not quite sure if you will got it as string or as JSON, in case it is a string you can convert it to JSON Object by doing `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`
Also as @vasif says, the JSON file shouldn´t have products = at start

Comment: I got my json file as he said... now it's time to do the AJAX call... but I don't understand which variable holds the json value at the end, I means, something like a return value...

Comment: this.responseText will contain the content of your file

Comment: I got an error: `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/report/bodyCalc/resources/products.json
Line Number 1, Column 1:` BTW, I wrote `var products = this.responseText` and after everything I wrote `console.log(products)`.

Comment: after  `  xhttp.open("GET", "products.json", true);` add `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: Are you testing using `file://` protocol? Requests made by that protocol will be blocked by security, you need an server in order to get the file correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152476/discussion-between-nima-bavari-and-frankusky).

Answer (score 0):

JSON file shall not have `products =` part.. instead use something like `{ 'products':[ ... ] }`

Can be achieved when you are trying to dump the file.

```
    content = {'products':content}
    with open('products.json', 'w') as outfile:
    # outfile.write('products = ')
    json.dumps(content, outfile)
    # outfile.write(';')
```

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: I did as you said and created the needed json file. BTW, I think you meant `content = {"products":content}` as single quotes are unaccaptable in json, am I right?

Comment: while single quotes are unaccepted in JSON. In python, they are acceptable. python binds string keys to values and create a python dict. The `dumps()` function of `json` package ( which you are calling later `json.dumps()` takes care of outputting the correct format with a double quotes`"`

Answer (score 0):

In the `window.onload` anonymous function declared in `s.js`,

```
    var products = JSON.parse(products)
```

declares a local function variable named `products` which shadows the global variable `products` with the same name and makes it inaccessible. Since the local variable is initially undefined, the code is equivalent to

```
    var products = JSON.parse(undefined);
```

which throws the same error. The simplest solution is to change the name of the variable used for the parsed data in the `onload` function to something else, to prevent it shadowing the global `products` value.

Other than that it seems to be working fine - a page of gymnasium photos with links underneath them.

Note that the 'products.json" file created in Python is a [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), not JSON, file.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an accepted answer, but I don't like it.  So here's mine.

Your products.json file is neither valid JSON not valid Javascript, but a combination of them which won't work in either.

You could update your python script to generate valid javascript and then load that script through a script tag named something like products.js:

```
products = [{ name : "value", name: "value"}, {name: "value", name:"value"}];
```

This would work fine if you only want to populate products once per page load.  If you're going for more ajax, where you want the value of products to change without reloading the page, then change your python script to generate valid JSON, and serve it up as a json file:

```
[{\"title\": \"\u0130DMAN ZALI\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/8223682236sport.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/194\"}, {\"title\": \"\u00dcZG\u00dc\u00c7\u00dcL\u00dcK HOVUZU\", \"caption\": \"http://www.theclub.az/bolme-img/8394983949hovuz.jpg\", \"source\": \"http://www.theclub.az/az/pages/150/195\"}]
```

Then, when you want to change the value of the products file, you can do something like this:

```
$.get("/path/to/products.json", null, null, "json")
    .done(function(r) {
        products = r;
    });
```

Comment: Issue is already solved, sir. But your answer is a very interesting one. (+1)